# Is there any convinient way that i can deepclone 'style' instance in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, clone

if a style is used, it can not be modified agaign. so i need a clone method. but its hard to implement.

what i want to do is implementing a cascading 'style' mechanism. for example, i set two style to the same frameworkelement. the same property of latter style will override the former one, while the different property remain unchanged.
but if i set the style property of the frameworkelement twice directly, the 1st style will be gone. so i use the baseon property of style class to do that. but now come across another problem, the style can not be modified after it's been set to a frameworkelement. 
so now i need a clone method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin,

I have written a CloneObject class which is exactly what you are looking for.  Check out my code here:

["Generic class for deep clone of Silverlight and C# objects"](http://yinyangme.com/blog/post/Generic-class-for-deep-clone-of-Silverlight-and-C-objects.aspx).

Jim

Answer (score 0):

thanks jim. i finally discards this 'clone' idea, because it's not that easy and seems to produce some buggy problem. so i try to create a xaml resource file, and every time i need to create a instance, i just load the xaml and call the XamlReader.load.
this can bring some performance issue, but i think the cost is acceptable. and i can do styling job in blend for that specified xaml file.